# Node js express is installed however still throwing not found error

Tags: node.js, express

i have installed `express` using:

```
npm install express -g
```

Now when i call:

`npm install express`

i get the following result:

```
    /home/marc/node
└── express@4.11.1
```

So when i want to run my hello world script:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

i still get the following error:

```
    Marc node # node /home/marc/nodejstest/server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marc/nodejstest/server.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem here?

my npm list:

```
    Marc node # npm list
/home/marc/node
└─┬ express@4.11.1
  ├─┬ accepts@1.2.2
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.7
  │ │ └── mime-db@1.5.0
  │ └── negotiator@0.5.0
  ├── content-disposition@0.5.0
  ├── cookie@0.1.2
  ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
  ├─┬ debug@2.1.1
  │ └── ms@0.6.2
  ├── depd@1.0.0
  ├── escape-html@1.0.1
  ├─┬ etag@1.5.1
  │ └── crc@3.2.1
  ├── finalhandler@0.3.3
  ├── fresh@0.2.4
  ├── media-typer@0.3.0
  ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
  ├── methods@1.1.1
  ├─┬ on-finished@2.2.0
  │ └── ee-first@1.1.0
  ├── parseurl@1.3.0
  ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
  ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.5
  │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
  │ └── ipaddr.js@0.1.6
  ├── qs@2.3.3
  ├── range-parser@1.0.2
  ├─┬ send@0.11.1
  │ ├── destroy@1.0.3
  │ ├── mime@1.2.11
  │ └── ms@0.7.0
  ├── serve-static@1.8.1
  ├─┬ type-is@1.5.5
  │ └─┬ mime-types@2.0.7
  │   └── mime-db@1.5.0
  ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
  └── vary@1.0.0
```

Comment: Do you also see express if you run the `npm list` command from the root of your application?

Comment: ive linked my npm list

Comment: Thanks, couple more questions... What is the name of the file with your express code in it? And what command are you using to run your node application?

Comment: The file name is server.js and i am using node /home/marc/nodejstest/server.js to execute it

Comment: Try just `node server` command from the root of your directory.

Comment: With this i get the same execption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69671/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-kris-hollenbeck).

Comment: I think express might be installed under /home/marc/node/node_modules while you are running under  /home/marc/nodejstest/. Either install expressjs under nodejstest or run npm install express -g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat, you will want to install express local instead of global.

**Local install and save to package.json:**

```
npm install express --save
```

**Express Docs:**

http://expressjs.com/

Also Note: the following command will help you determine which packages are globally installed. Global installs are okay, but sometimes there is some extra ground work needed. (IE, adding appropriate paths to your system paths)

**To see global packages:**

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

**Global vs Local:**

Some extra reading on global vs local.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/